Slavery and freedom
From moral justification view,  this verse about slavery is concerning to me, not really about the slavery, it's about the wife and children of a few slave that are left behind when he's freed. It states this in the verse

If his master gave him a wife while he was a slave and they had sons or daughters, then only the man will be free in the seventh year, but his wife and children will still belong to his master. [ ‭Exodus 21:4 NLT‬]

My questions are:

Would the kids continue as slaves for the master?
When the wife needs her conjugal rights,  what should happen?


These are good questions.

Yes, the kids most likely will continue as slaves for the master.  However, we have to be careful as this is not slavery in the sense it was practiced in Europe and America.  Slaves became part of the family and worked alongside their owners.

This is not easy to answer because we don't really know.  However being freed after seven years doesn't mean that he leaves his family. I don't think it means that the man stops being the husband of his wife.  They might still live together, however he can now choose to work somewhere else or start his own business.


I don't think it's so much different from today, if you and your wife work for a company and you decide to leave the company because your contract finished and you want to work somewhere else, your wife might be obligated to finish her contract first before she also can leave that company.  However, you still will live together in your house or flat.
